# Is PrinceXML exploitable if I control the template

Tags: web-application

In the middle of a web application pen test.  From the client side I can control a variable called template (to a URL which ultimately produces a pdf version of the page).  This variable contains what appears to be the outline of the pdf to be created.  Of particular interest is a part of this  `<%=myfield['contents']%>`.

After some examination this appears to be a princexml template. If I can control the template used by princexml, is there a path for exploitation here?  I have already tried xxe, but didn't appear to work (documentation seems to indicate that needs to be enabled via a command line switch).

Comment: The syntax seems pythonic to me.  I should add the client request is in json and looks as follows: `{"template":"pdf layout........<%myfield['contents']%>","myfield":{"contents":"blah"}}`  This would produce a pdf containing the text "blah."

Comment: Welcome to Security StackExchange! Even though you found this technology in a pentest, the identification of a remote web app is not a security question. At best, you *might* be on topic on the web developer's Stack Exchange site (but you'll have to check their criteria).

Comment: "Is X vulnerable in any way" is also off-topic because it is too broad (too many possible answers). And you can find the answer yourself by searching for CVEs or exploit-db.

Comment: Can you do a reflected file download?

Comment: @schroeder It isn't too broad when I specifically state the parameters of the problem.  Some possible answers would be "try xxe since princexml supports external identies" or "try the princexml <xi:include> directive."  Both of which I tried, but this configuration doesn't seem to be vulnerable to these.  I like your assumption though.

Comment: @wireghoul Unfortunately, no, but good idea.

Answer (score 0):

[SymbolHound](http://symbolhound.com/?q=%3C%25%3D) is a useful search engine for these sorts of things.

Most often I've seen this with ASP (ASP .NET?  ASP MVC?  I can't keep them straight) code.  It's also the same syntax used by ERB, a Ruby templating engine.